# Cant disable wifi multicast and constant arriving of data packets on rooted Android

Tags: wi-fi, battery-life

**Problem** :

I'm using public wifi in my college. (They won't allow alternatives). At least 40,000 students are using it regularly.

I keep receiving data packets from the moment I turn on wifi even though my device is idle and no other apps are using the wifi. You can see it here :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKzcO.jpg

This has been giving me nightmares lately. My active drain per hour was 6-7% and CPU usage was below 40% while browsing social media or stream videos.

After this problem, my active battery drain is 20-25% per hour, and CPU usage is always around 70%+ which leads to phone heating up and very poor screen on time.

**Solution** :

• Tried blocking qcom_rx_wakelock from the kernel (doesn't block data packets)

• Tried editing WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini from system/vendor/etc/wifi and added offloading features e.g. arpOffload and nsOffload. The guide can be found here -

[See here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-a-simple-guide-to-block-reduce-qcom_rx_wakelock-and-some-other-wifi-wakelocks.4280171/)

This works for the majority of the phones (my friends tried it and it worked) but sadly not for me.

*What I need* -

I have root and I'm looking for a way to block the packets from coming to my phone. I could disable wifi multicast from the router if it was my wifi. But it's not.

Is there anything I can do? Thanks for reading
Note : The problem disappears if I e different wifi which proves college wifi the culprit

Comment: Multicast in Wifi is often a problem because most Wifi system just convert it to a regular broadcast to all devices. If this is the problem source in your case it has to be solved by the Wifi network provider. I would make a PCAP network traffic dump using e.g. [PCAPDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emanuelef.remote_capture) and provide this capture to the college IT admins. The common way to stop this is to block multicast and broadcast traffic.

Comment: @Robert thank you so much for the comment. I already complained to IT office and they won't do anything about it cause only a few people reported it. It's sad there's nothing I can do from my phone.